# Power BI Ignoring Dates That Have Data

Tags: powerbi

I have googled this topic and searched the forums but I did not find anything...

The Data:
I have two data models that have a relationship via the field "date".
"Model A" shows the target production per day per asset  (static excel sheet upload)
"Model B" shows the actual production per day per asset, it is updated once per day and has hundreds of line items, for each item that was run across the asset (data flow)
What I want to show is the Production vs Actual for each asset per day, month etc. in a report

The situation:
On some days, assets have planned or unplanned downtimes during which they produce nothing, sometimes for one or more days in a row. When this happens, there are no rows for the corresponding dates for that asset in "Model B"

The issue:
I make a table with the following layout of columns:

Date - Source: Model A: Targets
Target - Source: Model A: Targets
Actual Production: Model B: Actuals
Difference: Calculated Measure

The issue occurs  when I filter the table on a specific asset. If that asset had a downtime say on December 1, so no production data, the table automatically removes the December 1 day from the table, even though the date column has the source "Model A" which has a Target Value for December 1.

Any idea how to get Power BI not to remove the date from the table?

Comment: Make sure that your resulting field has "0" as value when they have no production, instead of empty or NULL.

Comment: @iceblade Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately it is a data flow that is updated automatically, I don't add any manual data to the flow and I don't think the input data can be changed -  the output from our (very old) system is just no line item.

Comment: You can create a new column, showing 0 for empty values, then use that new column in your visual; something like: NewColumn = If(ISBLANK([originalColumn]), 0, [originalColumn])

Comment: @iceblade Thank you! Unfortunately herein lies my problem - there is no NULL or BLANK, there just is no row at all for Dec. 1 for the asset that has no production on this date. It goes from Nov 30 to Dec 2.

Comment: I think I have fixed the issue by adding a separate DATE TABLE! Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad you fixed it.